# Check that a process is a local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

Assume $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^d \times E$ is $C^2$ (on both parameters) and that $X_t=\int_0^t \sigma(X_s,I_s)dW_s$, where $(I_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is some discrete Markov Chain with finite state space $E$ that evolves independently of $X_t$, and $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Is it true that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale? To answer this I would be also pleased to see that this is indeed correct for a process $X_t=\int_0^t \sigma(X_s,s)dW_s$. I know this is true, but yet have not seen any proofs of it. Some references of older stack posts would be ok as well (I haven't myself found any so far).

Using the definition of [local martingales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale) I can create some stopping time sequence $\{\tau_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $\tau_n:= \{\inf t>0 : |X_t| \geq n \}$ that satisfies the first two prerequisites. I can see that continuity of $\sigma$ is important for this sequence to fit in the required conditions, as if implies $X_t$ is continuous (I admit I am not 100% convinced of this).

For the last part however, I'm not sure how to proceed. We are left to check that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_{\min(t,\tau_n)}$ is a martingale. How can I see this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing not, but have you seen the proof that $\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s$ is a local martingale for any predictable process $(\sigma_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$?

Comment: By a predictable process you mean some fixed function $\sigma$, right? @user6247850

Comment: Not deterministic - predictable.  Since this is a Brownian motion, it's fine if we just have $\sigma$ is an adapted process, i.e. $\sigma_t \in \mathcal F_t$ for all $t$.  Have you seen the theorem for that case?  Depending on your book, it could just be part of the definition of the stochastic integral that $\int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s$ is a local martingale for such $\sigma$.

Comment: Well here the question is a little more subtle as we are facing an sde not a diffusion but I still think that the result holds true.

Comment: I think the right way to prove this is to find a converging sequence (in a complete space of local martingales) of discrete local martingales approximations to the solution. Then the solution is itself a local martingale.

Comment: Thinking about it, isn't an actual martingale? We know that for any $T$ fixed, $(I_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ has only finitely many times, say at time $t_1,...,t_n$, there taking values of $e_1,...e_n$. Then we can write $X_t = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i}b(X_s,e_i)dW_s$. Then we easily see that $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$. What do you think? @TheBridge

Comment: Well this is part of the solution for sur I mean restricting on the discrete jumping times allows to patch different continuous sdes  if those are local martingales then you are done but you have to show that the continuous patches are local martingale though, this must be true with some smoothness conditions and maybe some L^2 metric space of local martingales (might not be the most general case)

Comment: For what smoothness condition on $b$ is $\int_0^t b(X_s)dW_s$ a local martingale? @TheBridge